# R: Symmetrical relationship matrix from frequency data frame

Tags: r, matrix, distance, matching

I have a data frame with frequencies in R like this:

```
    V1 V2 V3 V4
row1 1  2  0  1
row2 0  6  0  3
row3 3  0  0  0
row4 0  0  2  0
row5 4  1  0  0
row6 3  0  1  1
(more rows)

a<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,0,1,0,6,0,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,4,1,0,0,3,0,1,1),byrow=T,ncol=4))
```

I want a function to calculate, for each row, matches between columns where both values are > 0, so I get a relationship matrix for V1-V4, like this:

```
    V1 V2 V3 V4
V1
V2   2
V3   1  0
V4   2  2  1
```

Is there some handy function available? Or how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R method using `combn`, `sapply`, and `rowSums`.

```
# get the pairwise combination of variables
varComb <- combn(names(df), 2)
varComb
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "V1" "V1" "V1" "V2" "V2" "V3"
[2,] "V2" "V3" "V4" "V3" "V4" "V4"

# get the counts
counts <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(varComb)),
                 function(i) sum(rowSums(df[,varComb[,i]] > 0) == 2))
```

Here, The variable combinations are used to subset the data frame, which is converted to a logical matrix based on whether or not the values are greater than 0. The rows are sumed together and are counted (using `sum`) based on whether or not the result is equal to 2. `sapply` allows us to apply this counting to every pair of variables present in varComb.

```
# put these into a data frame
setNames(data.frame(t(varComb), counts), c("var1", "var2", "counts"))
  var1 var2 counts
1   V1   V2      2
2   V1   V3      1
3   V1   V4      2
4   V2   V3      0
5   V2   V4      2
6   V3   V4      1
```

Putting these result together, we can use `setNames`, which allows us to create a data frame and apply names to the variables in one line.

---

to put this result into matrix, you could use `cbind` and matrix subsetting:

```
# construct empty matrix
tempMat <- matrix(NA, 4, 4)

# fill it in
tempMat[cbind(as.integer(substr(dfNew$var2, 2, 2)),
              as.integer(substr(dfNew$var1, 2, 2)))] <- dfNew$counts

tempMat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    2   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    1    0   NA   NA
[4,]    2    2    1   NA
```

The `as.integer` and `substr` extract the rows and columns in which to place the values, `cbind` converts this output into a matrix which is used for matrix subetting.

Comment: That is a neat idea, but is there a way to get the output as a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Okay after a bit of fiddling around here's what I came up with:

```
a<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,0,1,0,6,0,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,4,1,0,0,3,0,1,1),byrow=T,ncol=4))
a[a>0]<-1
a<-t(a)    
mat<-outer(1:nrow(a), 1:nrow(a), FUN=Vectorize(function(x,y) sum(a[x,]!=0 & a[y,]!=0)))
mat[upper.tri(mat,diag=T)] <- 0
```

Not pretty, but it seems to work.

Comment: A variation, `t(a > 0) %*% (a > 0) * lower.tri(matrix(,ncol(a), ncol(a)))` also seems to work. True/false for the inequality is treated as 1/0 in the multiplication.